# Color swatches in select list with CSS :Before pseudo element. Only works in Firefox

Tags: php, html, css, pseudo-element

I am working on a custom stole configurator that can be viewed here: [stoles.com/stoles](http://stoles.com/stoles)
The site is password protected, username is: "alex", password is: "superman".

I have a standard html select list for stole color, trim color and text color. I am trying to add color swatches to the left of each select option. I have implemented a CSS pseudo element, ":before" to accomplish this. The problem is that it only work in firefox, no chrome, safari or IE. I need it to work at least in chrome, safari, IE9+ and Firefox. Is there any way to get a color swatch next to my select option without using a crazy jquery list to select type of plugin? I'd really like to stick with a standard select list here.

Here is my code:

```
<select class="" name="stoleColor" id="stoleColor">
                    <option value="">...</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cAntiqueGold" value="antique-gold">Antique Gold</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cBlack" value="black">Black</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cBrown" value="brown">Brown</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cEmeraldGreen" value="emerald-green">Emerald Green</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cGold" value="gold">Gold</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cGreen" value="green">Green</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cHunterGreen" value="hunter-green">Hunter Green</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cLightBlue" value="light-blue">Light Blue</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cMaroon" value="maroon">Maroon</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cNavyBlue" value="navy-blue">Navy Blue</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cOrange" value="orange">Orange</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cPink" value="pink">Pink</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cPurple" value="purple">Purple</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cRed" value="red">Red</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cRoyalBlue" value="royal-blue">Royal Blue</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cSilver" value="silver">Silver</option>
                    <option class="colorSwatch cWhite" value="white">White</option>
                </select>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
    option.colorSwatch:before {
    content: " ";
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border:2px solid #ebebeb;
    margin-right:10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

option.cAntiqueGold:before {
    background:#9C6600;
}
```

Comment: I don't think pseudo-elements are supported on input elements at all in these browsers

Comment: [An alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/Va4At/), but you still need js to collect the selected value, so you might as well use JS to generate the list